# redirect to 404 with status 301

Tags: nginx

When a page is not found, I wanna redirect with status code 301 to 404.html.

So far what I have is, you can land on 404.html, with status code 301 right away:

```
error_page 404 =301 /404.html;
```

But like that there's no redirect, so the current URL still wrong.

Example, to user should be:
site.com/non-existing-page -> document/redirect 301 -> site.com/404

Answer (score 0):

This should work, consider reading manual about [error_page](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#error_page) directive:

```
location /404 {
  error_page 301 = 404.html;
}
```

Comment: like that it didn't land on 404.html, neither redirected with 301. Nginx version would make difference here? (using 1.20)

Comment: Okay, lets dig into logs, show us your `access.log` and `error.log`

Comment: on error log: [error] 9260#0: *204 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/404" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.71.10.126, server: _, request: "GET /404 HTTP/1.1"... With the other syntax, it didn't throw this error.

Comment: @Sevila do you actually have `404.html` in your root folder? By default it seems to be `/usr/share/nginx/html`